# Unable to parse json data in store sencha

Tags: json, extjs, sencha-touch

```
 [
{
 "@aircraftId": "8a8aa3943e3ee05c013e3f59930d06df",
 "tailNumber": "QA14",
 "stockNumberCode": "ST-AC-B5S"
},
{
 "@aircraftId": "8a8aa3943e62f9de013e63433f790034",
 "tailNumber": "QACU2",
 "stockNumberCode": "QA-ST-CU2"
 },
{
 "@aircraftId": "8a8aa3943e62f9de013e63455362004b",
 "tailNumber": "453201",
 "stockNumberCode": "SN453201"
},
{
"@aircraftId": "8a8aa3943e3ee05c013e3eea2db3000d",
"tailNumber": "HR455",
"stockNumberCode": "HR ST THUR"
},
{
  "@aircraftId": "8a8aa3943e62f9de013e6356190601a2",
"tailNumber": "N171",
"stockNumberCode": "E171"
},
{
"@aircraftId": "8a8a95ca38104bbb01381fcaf8e43831",
"tailNumber": "N760CP",
"stockNumberCode": "E170"
},
{
"@aircraftId": "8a8aa3943e3ee05c013e3f1896bb065e",
"tailNumber": "123",
"stockNumberCode": "ST-12345"
},
{
 "@aircraftId": "8a8aa3943e3ee05c013e405d25f70846",
"tailNumber": "143",
"stockNumberCode": "MPR"
},
{
"@aircraftId": "8a9e82af3eef9d3a013ef0805ca30022",
"tailNumber": "ARN 0529",
"stockNumberCode": "ACS 0529"
},
{
"@aircraftId": "8a9e82af3ef3d12a013ef41de5590067",
"tailNumber": "ARN 0530",
"stockNumberCode": "ACS 0530"
},
{
 "@aircraftId": "8a9e82af3ef3d12a013ef41c976e0058",
 "tailNumber": "ARN 30",
 "stockNumberCode": "ACS 30"
 }
]
```

this is my json respone from rest servcie here is my model and store for this

```
      Ext.define('FCELB.store.AircraftStore', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
     config: {
        model: 'FCELB.model.AircraftModel',
        storeId: 'aircraftstore',
        autoLoad:false,
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
             method:'Get',
             url: 'http://10.30.2.139:8080/xl/api/1/aircrafts/json',

            reader: {
                type: 'json'

            },

            headers: {

               'Accept':'application/json'

            } ,
            listeners: {
                load : function(store, records, successful, operation, eOpts) {
                    console.log('Aircrafts load..');
                }
            }
        }

    }


});
```

can you please chek am i missing some thing in my store class i am abel to parse successsfully seemsas i am not gettignissue with json reading but in call back am getting result object length is zero

Here is my store call for the json

```
        var store = Ext.create('FCELB.store.AircraftStore');
        //store.load();
         store.load({
         callback: function (records, operation, success) {
            console.log('rest service called' + records);

        },
        failure: function (record, operation) {
            console.log('invode failed returend records' + record);
        },
        success: function (record, operation) {
            console.log('in success function' + record);
        }

    });
```

Here is my modal definition for the above json format

```
Ext.define('FCELB.model.AircraftModel', {
 extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
 config: {
    fields: [

        {name: 'tailNumber', mapping:'tailNumber' }

    ]
    //hasMany:'aircraft'

  }
```

});

Comment: Can you also post the model definition?

Comment: Also, why do you use jsonp and not json? If you actually need it, you need to format the server response with a callback.

Comment: My rest call is cross doamin so using jsonp as its allowig cross doamin request and i have written callback am not getting result records data in call back able to see the json data in network section from browser

Comment: Do you use the `callback` parameter that is sent to the sever, to name the callback in the response?

Comment: And, the response type for jsonp should be text/javascript. But you define headers to accept application/json

Comment: my server response is json type hwo to use callbacl param ?

Comment: In my json response i dont have root element is that valid json?

Comment: I would start by reading the [documentation for jsonp proxy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP). There are server side examples there.

Comment: It is valid without root, but the response shouldn't be json, the response should be a javascript method invocation, that includes the json object as a parameter.

Comment: in above code snippets i have called store.load method is that the one talking about right

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.. It is pretty clear to me now that your server response is not correct for jsonp.

Comment: yeah i came to know that through documentation response format for jsonp should be embed with response key right thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

try this...
on your store

...
reader: {
     type: 'json',
     root: 'items'
},
...

on your json response, change it to...
`{
   "items": [
    {
        "@aircraftId": "8a8aa3943e3ee05c013e3f59930d06df",
        "tailNumber": "QA14",
        "stockNumberCode": "ST-AC-B5S"
    },
    {
        "@aircraftId": "8a8aa3943e62f9de013e63433f790034",
        "tailNumber": "QACU2",
        "stockNumberCode": "QA-ST-CU2"
    },
    ...
    ]
}`